# Coroutine only partially executing

Tags: unity, c#, coroutines

I have a Coroutine that I use to pull and spawn an enemy in my game. This coroutine works perfectly fine, with the exception of the very first call. I am fairly certain this is because I am probably loading something before it is ready, but I don't know enough to know where.

This is my code (Note the Debug.Log entries). I have removed whatever I think is irrelevant code.

1. EnemyHandler.cs

   ```
   public class EnemyHandler : MonoBehaviour
   {
   public int mob_id;
   IEnumerator LoadMob()
   {
       Debug.Log("Checkpoint 1");

       WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
       form.AddField("mob_id",mob_id);
       WWW www = new WWW("my-url-here",form);
       yield return www;
       Debug.Log("@@@@@@ Checkpoint 2 @@@@@@");
       string[] webResults = www.text.Split('\t');

       int returncode = int.Parse(webResults[0]);

       switch (returncode)
       {
           case 0:
           //Mob Loaded Successfully
           //Mob variables are set here
           Debug.Log("@@@@@@ Checkpoint 3 @@@@@@");
           break;

           default:
           Debug.Log("Error!");
           break;
       }

   }

    public void CallMobLoad(int requested_mob_id)
    {
        mob_id = requested_mob_id;
        StartCoroutine(LoadMob());
        Debug.Log("Coroutine called! Checkpoint 0");
    }
   }
   ```

2.GameManager.cs (This is my primary class)

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject spawnManager;
    public static EnemyHandler thisenemy;

    void Start()
    {
     thisenemy = spawnManager.AddComponent<EnemyHandler>();
     thisenemy.CallMobLoad(1);
    }
}
```

CallMobLoad is called once at Start, and every time a monster dies. It never works when called in Start(), but always works after that.

Furthermore, the first call only calls the first 2 Debug.Logs "Checkpoint 0" and "Checkpoint 1", none of the other checkpoints are hit. Every subsequent call works correctly and hits all checkpoints.

I really want to learn how/why this happens, Any help is greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:** I have fixed this by turning Start into an IEnumerator, and adding a `yield return` to `thisenemy.CallMobLoad(mobloadtemp);`

Still not sure if this is the best way to do this, so please do advise.

Comment: Please post your solution as an Answer, not embedded in the question itself.

Comment: Wasn't sure if I was right. I'll take that to mean that I am, then. Thank you! @DMGregory

Comment: If the solution works, it works. I don't have any insight for you at the moment about why this would work differently than what you had before.

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed this by turning the function I use to initialize the Coroutine into an IEnumerator, and adding a `yield return` to the call.

(The same effect can be achieved by changing `Start` from `void` to `IEnumerator`, if the Coroutine is initialized in `Start`).

I don't know if this is the best solution, but this solves the problem completely.